# How to access Docker from outside the machine its hosted on?

Tags: docker

So currently, I have a Virtualbox running on my Mac. I can access the docker containers from my mac perfectly fine by going to 192.168.99.100:port. That port was exposed with -p with the following line:

`docker run -p 49160:8080 -d node-web-app`.

So, now I want to access that Docker container from someone else's computer. That user will be in the same network as I am.

I tried doing port forwarding on my mac like:

```
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 5000 -> 192.168.99.100 port 49160
```

I thought that this would forward any requests to my IP address with that Port to the Docker Container, but it doesn't seem to work. Has anyone else attempted to solve this?

Comment: So you are running a virtualBox, and docker is running inside that virtualBox ???

Comment: What is your PC's IP address ?

Comment: And also please share what is the output of `ifconfig` ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure (using tcpdump) that there's traffic coming to your port 5000. Then make sure there's traffic coming to your docker machine at 49160. Finally check the traffic in the container. You will find out this way which machine is dropping the traffic. My guess is you need to configure the firewall on the 192.168.99.100 box.